# PostgreSQL DO WHILE LOOP

Tags: postgresql, loops

I'm using PGadmin 4 SQL and trying to write a query that checks every line of an order to see if a specific criteria applies.
Effectively I have an existing query that checks all outstanding lines to see if they can be satisfied by current stock availability based on multiple criteria.  Then, I want the results to be further filtered if any line from the results is part of an order where at least one line can't be satisfied.
Simple 2 x 3 line order's example:

- Order 1
  Line 1, Part A, 10 ordered, 10 in stock
  Line 2, Part B, 10 ordered, 10 in stock
  Line 3, Part C, 10 ordered, 10 in stock
- Order 2
  Line 1, Part D, 10 ordered, 10 in stock
  Line 2, Part E, 10 ordered, 10 in stock
  Line 3, Part F, 10 ordered, 0 in stock

So, Orders 1 & 2 both appear in my current results as they have a line/s from the order that are available to be shipped.
I want SQL to go through each order line and, for example, add 1 to a declared integer if stock isn't available, then loop to the next line of the order and repeat until all lines checked; thus, if all lines results added to the integer equal zero then all lines can be satisfied and if the result is 1+ then all lines can't be satisfied.

Please ask questions if any of that doesn't make any sense.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as in tabular format (the way your SQL client also show it). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. Together with the (formatted) sample input data, please also include the _output_ you want to get

Comment: It seems you are looking for Orders Lines vs the inventory and determine if the complete order can be filled with current inventory. But the desired result is unclear. Do you want the orders that *can* be filled or the orders that *can not* be filled or do you want an indication for each order as to the ability to fulfill it.